# Unpermitted parameters for an attribute that has an array of values

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

This is what the parameters look like for my `Node#update`:

```
Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"F1HGLeI9E=", "node"=>{"name"=>"Lesty", "parents"=>["13", "35", ""], "family_tree_id"=>"2"}, "commit"=>"Update Node", "id"=>"38"}
```

This is my `NodesController`:

```
private

def node_params
  params.require(:node).permit(:user_id, :family_tree_id, :name, :description, :parent_id, :parent, :parents)
end
```

But when I try to update the `@node` object that produces the above log, I get this error:

```
Node Load (1.1ms)  SELECT  "nodes".* FROM "nodes"  WHERE "nodes"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", 38]]
Unpermitted parameters: parents
   (1.7ms)  BEGIN
   (1.3ms)  COMMIT
Redirected to http://localhost:3000/nodes/38
Completed 302 Found in 21ms (ActiveRecord: 4.0ms)
```

It is important to note that the `parents` attribute for my `@node` object is inherited via the `gem ancestry` and not directly on the `Node` model or via an association.

Thoughts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to tell strong_parameters to expect an array if I recall correctly.

```
def node_params
  params.require(:node).permit(:user_id, :family_tree_id, :name, :description, :parent_id, :parent, parents: [])
end
```

Comment: I figured that I had to tell it to expect an array, I just wasn't sure how. Thanks much...this works perfectly!

Answer (score 1):

You can simply try this

```
 private

def node_params
  params.require(:node).permit(:name, :family_tree_id, parents: [])
end
```